# Winamp crashes on program startup all of a sudden

Tags: winamp, rainmeter

Very recently, my Winamp started crashing each time it starts up.
I have not upgraded recently, and have been running the same minimalistic theme (blackdawn) for about a year now.

I have been running it in conjunction with Rainmeter (Gaia Winamp Widget) without issue as well.

Yesterday after a computer restart, it just started crashing every time I tried to load it.

I'm running Windows XP SP3, and I know that my Winamp version is at least 5.3 (can't access the About...) since it won't load.

I hear that simply uninstalling/reinstalling is the easiest way to fix this sort of issue, but unfortunately I'm at work behind a firewall that blocks sites that offer Winamp as a download (winamp.com..cnet...etc).

Anybody have a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling/reinstalling IS the easiest way to fix this sort of issue, maybe even the only one.

And regarding the firewall, can't you simply bring the download to work om a CD or USB key?

Comment: I can, but that means waiting until I get home :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - Winamp would start, play a couple of seconds and exit. Drove me daft.

I found it was caused by having a USB Sansa player plugged into the PC.

Disconnect the Sansa - all well was well

Connect the Sansa - Winamp crashed everytime

Damn nuisance.

Comment: it seems that if winamp is unhappy once, it will forever be unhappy until its reinstalled

Comment: Time to look for another player methinks. Thanks.